# Should there be a migration path to Software Recommendations?

Tags: feature-request, migration

Given all the "which tech to use" questions this site seems to get, [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) looks like it might be a good place to migrate the "which tech" questions to (at least the "well defined" ones). At the least, it looks like a good location to redirect some of those users to.

[This recent question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/106619/urban-scene-modling-serious-game-platform) looks like one that might be a good candidate for migration (specific tech being looked at, requirements for project being specified).

[Software Recommendations question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that directing them to that site is probably worthwhile.

I don't necessarily agree about a defined migration path being necessary; I'm not convinced that the majority of the questions we close with that particular close reason would be directly on-topic and appropriate on the Recommendations beta (that is, would be good questions for that site without edits). I'm also not convinced we'd have enough users actually voting for the migration of individual questions for it to see significant practical use; we still have an overall problem with achieving closure via non-binding votes as it is.

Note that we *can* migrate questions there now, you just need to flag them for moderator attention and make a note to that effect.